# How to change the css of a text input using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a cell with a class called OnHandClass.  I have an input field inside the cell and I have added a double click event to the cell and have tried many ways to change the visibility of the closest input element.  Three are listed below.  What am I missing ?

```
 <input type="text" class="OnHandEditClass" value="1" style="display: none;">

  <td class="OnHandClass">
  1
  <input type="text" class="OnHandEditClass" value='1'>
  </td>

 $('.OnHandClass').dblclick(function (evt) {              

            $(this).next(":text").css("display", "inline");
            $(this).next("input[type='text']").show();
            $(this).closest('input').css("display", "inline");               

        });
```

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/find/

Comment: your input has class of `OnHandEditClass`, not `OnHandClass`.

Comment: @PlantTheIdea - OP said the "cell" has the class `OnHandClass`. Presumably the input is in a table cell however the OP failed to include that code if it is.

Comment: @j08691 - ah, so they just provided an incomplete codebase for the question. my bad.

Comment: Either that or a bad description.

Comment: I will add more code for context.  Sorry guys.

Comment: Yes.  It is a cell that has the OnHandClass.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `.find()` (or `.children()`) should do it:

```
$('.OnHandClass').dblclick(function (evt) {
    $(this).find(":text").show();
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/xho8dsep/)**

`.next()` searches the immediate sibling and `.closest()` looks up the DOM, so neither of those should have worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <input type="text" class="OnHandClass"/>
    <input type="text" class="OnHandEditClass" value="1" style="display: none;">

$('.OnHandClass').dblclick(function(evt) {
    $(this).closest('input').next().css("display", "inline");
});
```

Comment: Mike.  Please see my edit above.  My OnHandClass is on a table cell.

Answer (score 0):

If your input is inside your td as you said, use .children:

```
$('.OnHandClass').dblclick(function() {
    $(this).children('input').css("display", "inline");
});
```

.children should be the fasted way in your case.